# Large projects built on Lisp

Tags: lisp, racket

What are some examples of large projects (e.g., web sites) programmed in Lisp or a Lisp framework?

Comment: Look for some projects done with Clojure.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406729 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172798

Answer (score 8):

Most of emacs and its many extensions/modes are written in [emacs lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp).

Answer (score 5):

The Orbitz travel web site runs on Lisp: http://www.paulgraham.com/carl.html

Answer (score 5):

The Operating System and in fact the *entire* system on the various Lisp Machines was written in Lisp. In fact, while the commercial Lisp Machines often used more traditional languages such as Verilog and VHDL, on some of the more "researchy" Lisp Machines, even the *CPU* was written in Lisp.

Lispers just *love* their language. They'd rather write *everything* in it. (In that way, they are similar to Smalltalkers.)

Answer (score 3):

There's [a discussion from Lambda The Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2491) from a couple years back that's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The early versions of Reddit were written in Lisp.  The Yahoo Store (formerly ViaWeb) was written in Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

[Flightcaster](http://Flightcaster.Com/) is a heavy user of [Clojure](http://Clojure.Org/). While Ruby on Rails provides the pretty face, all the "thinking" (statistical analysis / machine learning) is done in Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

These bioinformatics platforms are both built on Lisp:

BioCyc (sorry, can't post a link -- try biocyc dot org)

BioBike (sorry, can't post a link -- try biobike dot org)

As was this commercial application for pharmaceutical chemists:

http://www.franz.com/success/customer_apps/bioinformatics/mdl_story.lhtml

All are fairly large projects, at least in terms of complexity (I've worked on all three of them).

Answer (score 0):

Some links from the ALU website:

http://wiki.alu.org/Success%20Stories

http://wiki.alu.org/Industry%20Application

http://wiki.alu.org/Research%20Organizations

Answer (score 0):

GBBopen is an actively maintained AI framework, a blackboard system, in Lisp
-> http://gbbopen.org/overview.html